# Use arcmap layout for profiles or Vertical ortho-images (walls) instead of horizontal

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, scale-bar, pictometry

I have designed an Arcmap layout and use it within an arcpy script to generate lots of pages of a pdf report, one page per polygon I have drawn (changing title, scalebar, polygon being highlighted in an inset).

Now, I would like to use the same layout and all its elements, but not with zenital orthophotographies from my arcmap project, but for profiles or vertical ortho-images (for example, for a building I might have elevation or profile of the south, north, ... walls). Although they are not zenithal, these vertical profiles have georeferencing information, which stores the pixel width and height projected on the globe, which can be used to generate the scalebars for example.

I've had no luck trying to find the way to do it in arcmap - which is by design intended to horizontal ortho-projections. If you have any hint, please advise. The pictometry tool gets close to that, using oblique imagery, but not parallel projections.

Comment: ArcMap is 2 dimensional from what I'd call a "top-down" perspective.  It won't show building photos vertically.  ArcScene and ArcGlobe are the 3D applications in the ArcGIS Desktop suite.  You could fake it by making your vertical images lie flat in the ArcMap view, however your width/height tags wouldn't be taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have not yet found a way to create a layout in ArcScene and ArcGlobe, I can just export a render of the 3D view. Is it something possible? Moreover, I cannot import these vertical ortho-images in ArcScene or ArcGlobe. The things I'd like to add to the ortho-image is scale, title and position - which I can obtain by converting the vertical raster imported into ArcMap to a polygon, which with a non null stroke width, shows the locatino of the data.